# How to access self in class method objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method

I havea Utility class that uses class methods. I am trying to refer to self in the class method but can't. I was wondering how would I declare the following in a class method:

```
[MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.window animated:YES];
```

`self.window` it says member reference type `struct objc_class *' is a pointer; maybe you meant to use '->'`

Another problem that relates to not being able to call `self` is how would I refer to a declared  `@property` in my `.h` in a class method in my `.m`.

Here is my class method:

```
.m
+ (void)showHUD
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
    [MRProgressOverlayView showOverlayAddedTo:self.window animated:YES];

    //I would preferably like to call my property here instead
}


.h
@property (nonatomic) MRProgress * mrProgress;
```

Comment: I think maybe you're misunderstanding the use of a class method. Calling class methods is not the same as calling a method on an instance of a class because you don't have an instance of that class. There is no "self" with a class method in this context, because self refers to the instance of the object that was created.

Comment: @Aaron you are right, I think I was misunderstanding it. Thanks for the the detailed explanation.

Comment: Technically, I believe that `self` refers to the class, in a class method.

Comment: Not just technically. Inside a class method, "self" is the class. You can use it to call other class methods, for example. On the other hand, a class method would have not a clue what instance of the class you want to access. And while instance have a "window" property, the class itself doesn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of a class method is that it is not part of a specific instance. Inside of a class method, `self` is the class.

If you need to be tied to a specific instance, then it should be an instance method. If you want a static method that accesses a specific instance, then pass that instance (`self`) to it (though it's hard to imagine many cases where that makes sense).

In the above example, `showHUD` should be an instance method almost certainly. If that doesn't make sense for some reason, then it should be:

```
+ (void)showHUDForWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
```

You can then call it as `showHUDForWindow:self.window` and use that as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that, it was very helpful. So should a class method not have propertys either? Or how would you refer to them within the class? I really appreciate the detail :)

Comment: Class methods can only refer to type properties (class variables for classes, static variables for structs). See "Type Property Syntax" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html). But class variables aren't yet implemented in the Swift compiler (static variables in structs are). That said, non-factory class methods are somewhat rare anyway. Typically you should create an instance and call methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a singleton pattern. Singleton pattern assumes that the only instance of your class exists. Since it's the only instance, you can then use it from class methods.

Example implementation:

```
+ (MyClass*)sharedInstance {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static MyClass *sharedMyClass;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
        sharedMyClass = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyClass;
}
```

Then you can access the shared instance via `[MyClass sharedInstance]`, for example:

```
+ (void)doSomethingCool {
   [[self sharedMyClass] doSomething];
}
```

Comment: Just because the OP is confused between class methods and instance methods is absolutely _not_ a reason to gravitate to singletons. [Singletons are evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?SingletonsAreEvil), so use them sparingly and only where appropriate. In this case, where he's just struggling to figure out how to get a reference to the window, introducing a singleton only clouds the issue further.